# from sql query to mysql equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql

Please, i have this query which is in sql

```
select sum(lhd.sasih)-sum(lhd.sasid) as sasi,lhd.kartllg as kartllg
from e2013..levizjehd lhd,supersick_db..produkt as prod
where  lhd.kartllg=prod.kodfinance
group by lhd.kartllg
```

I need to write it's equivalent but in mysql...
I get this error:

```
Invalid object name 'e2013..levizjehd'.
```

What i need is to translate it in mysql query, but i don't know what .. stand for in sql.
I'd appreciate some help please.

How i connect

```
$host="192.168.10.250\\f501";
$uid="sa";
$passVal="";
$database="SUPERSICK_DB";
$objConnect = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database;",$uid, $passVal ) or die("Connection could not established");
```

Thanks!

Comment: **e2013** is the DataBase name and **levizjehd** is Object name in MS-SQL. It is written in Three-Part-Name.

Comment: HOW CAN I GET this in php?
how should i form the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is referring the database name. So like 'e2013' is one DB and 'supersick_db' is another. The first contains the 'levizjeh' table the other one the 'produkt' table.

If you have both tables inside the same mysql than you can skip the name and the .. altogether.

```
SELECT SUM(lhd.sasih)-SUM(lhd.sasid) AS sasi, lhd.kartllg AS kartllg
FROM levizjehd lhd, produkt prod
WHERE lhd.kartllg = prod.kodfinance
GROUP BY lhd.kartllg
```

You can improve the query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(lhd.sasih)-SUM(lhd.sasid) AS sasi, lhd.kartllg AS kartllg
FROM levizjehd lhd
INNER JOIN produkt prod ON lhd.kartllg = prod.kodfinance
GROUP BY lhd.kartllg
```

Comment: I need to get this info from sql to php, so, i have updated my connection way in my question, could you please take a look?

Comment: thats a different question, please ask it differently (or even better: do some research, that question has already been answered)

Comment: sorry, i don't know if its a different thing..
this is how i connect to sql server in general, this is how i use it, but with this query i don't know how to put it together..

Comment: @alandr The way how you create the connection is database specific and has nothing at all to do with any query. So the question "How do I connect to a MySQL" is a different one to "How does this query work?" Please post one question here for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think Angelo's covered the question but note that the following aren't equivalent:

```
SUM(lhd.sasih) - SUM(lhd.sasid)
SUM(lhd.sasih - ldh.sasid)
```

These expressions can potentially return different results if either column is nullable: aggregates ignore nulls. E.g. if row one is {10, null} and row two is {100, 50} the first returns 10 + 10 - 50; the second 100 - 50.